# Add Same Content in two different tabs

Tags: tabs, javafx-2

I am facing one strange issue in my application.

I want to duplicate UI on two different tabs (i.e two different tabs will hold same VBox Object in its container).

What I am expecting is rather than creating two different VBox object to add to Tab1 & Tab2 I will create one single VBox Object,fill it with desired contents and then add same object to Tab1 & Tab2.

What is currently happening is If I add that UI to Tab1 only then it is displayed properly.But If I add same object to Tab2 then it disappears from Tab1.

Below is sample code I am using.

```
@FXML
private Tab tab1, tab2;

Label label=new Label("Sample");

tab1.setContent(label);
tab2.setContent(label);
```

What is my assumption here it in both tab content I will see **Sample** Text.

But Sample text is only shown in Tab2 and not Tab1.(Tab1 is shown empty.)

I am newbie in Javafx so please bear with me if I am asking a stupid question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) which is the base class for all JavaFX graphical elements, is a member of a tree structure. As such, each node can have at most one [parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#parentProperty%28%29). So obviously, under the scenes, when you put your `VBox` to another tab, JavaFX assigns it to another parent. In the same time it removes it from the old parent, so as to keep the node tree consistent.

I think you would have better chance either:

1. Implementing a component that encapsulates the creation of the the `VBox` and its children, if you only want code reuse.
2. Live with the fact that the `VBox` will be only at one tab at a time. You will have to listen to some tab activation event and assign the `VBox` to the activated tab every time.

Comment: Yups I already figured out point 2 and solved my issue.But your explanation did clear my concepts.Cheers Bro :)